# Electrostatics- relating to proving or disproving a theorem

Tags: electromagnetism

Verify this theorem below:

Theorem: Suppose a conductor carrying a net charge Q, when placed in an external electric field E, experience a force F; if the external field is now reversed, the force also reverses.

what if we stipulate that the external field is uniform?

Answer (score 0):

It should make no difference the type of Field. If it is uniform again the integral over the charge (surface) distribution would be the same but with opposite sign.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?